# Getting more detailed error info from Python lxml library

Tags: python, xml, xsd, lxml

I'm using [lxml](http://lxml.de/) to validate XML files against XSDs. Works fine. However, when there's a missing element, it doesn't provide info on exactly which element is missing. I.e. starting with a valid XML that validates against an XSD, if you then remove one required element, it gives you an error as expected.

However, rather than pointing out that specific element as the missing element, it gives a generic "..Missing child element(s). Expected is one of [a list of candidate elements]". The error is somewhat useful, however, I don't understand why it can't tell exactly which required element is missing if it's given an XSD. Is there a way to make it smarter in this regard and provide this info?

The outline of my script is something like:

```
from lxml import etree
xmlschema_doc = etree.parse('c:/xmlvalidation/schema.xsd')
xmlschema = etree.XMLSchema(xmlschema_doc)
doc = etree.parse(''c:/xmlvalidation/test.xml')
try:
    xmlschema.assertValid(doc)
    print('XML valid, schema validation ok.')

except etree.DocumentInvalid as err:
    print(err)
```

Comment: If the schema allows several elements in given position, lxml cannot single out one of them. A list of candidate elements is the best you can get.

Comment: @mzjn current lxml does store line by line errors information lxml.etree.XMLSchema('').error_log See: https://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#errors-and-messages